# Помогите с запятой!

Tags: пунктуация

«*Но, когда он...*»

Нужна запятая?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Эта тема называется "**Присоединительные союзы перед подчинительными союзами**".

Присоединительные союзы **И, А** обычно относятся к подчинительному союзу, в этом случае запятая между ними не ставится, а для  присоединительного союза **НО** возможны оба варианта:

А) Присоединительный союз НО относится к главному предложению: пауза, запятая ставится: **Но, как ни** мы ни старались, дойти до  устья реки в этот день нам так и не удалось.

Б) Присоединительный союз НО относится к придаточному предложению:  нет паузы, запятая не ставится: **Но когда** после долгой разлуки он вновь увидел  родные места, что-то защемило в его сердце.

Обычно нет необходимости  в постановке запятой после  присоединительных союзов перед подчинительными союзами , так как в этом случае придаточная часть приобретает **вставочный характер** (это  надо учитывать при авторском обособлении союза).

[**Розенталь §110. Запятая на стыке двух союзов**](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/49.htm#%D0%B7_04)

2. Запятая обычно не ставится между присоединительным союзом (после точки) и союзом подчинительным, например: И кто вы такой, я знаю; А зачем это говорится, мне непонятно. Возможность постановки запятой **после других присоединительных союзов связана с интонационно-смысловым выделением придаточного предложения,** например: Однако, если вы так настаиваете на своем предложении, я готов его принять.

Comment: _Sibylla: "Возможность постановки запятой **после других присоединительных союзов связана с интонационно-смысловым выделением придаточного предложения**"_. ===

В общем случае -- да, такое обособление иногда возможно. Ну а в конкретном? Вопрос был про предложение, начинающееся с «Но(,) когда он…». Можете ли предложить предложение, начинающееся именно с этих слов,   при котором бы Вы поставили запятую между "Но" и "когда"?

Comment: Сначала я вообще не хотел отвечать на вопрос "Но когда тра-та-та", но потом ответила в общем виде. Примеры с запятой: Но, когда после полёта Гагарина в США заговорили о "ракетном отставании от СССР", к идее Дорнбергера вернулись. [Иван Сафронов. 2000]. Но, когда кто-то рассказал про него, я не удивился: так и должно быть! [Юрий Трифонов. Дом на набережной (1976)] .  Я лично поставила бы запятую, если бы у меня было желание логически подчеркнуть союз НО и придать придаточному вставочный характер.

Answer (score 0):

> *«Но, когда он...»*
>
> Нужна запятая?

Скорее всего, будет **не нужна**. У меня не получается придумать продолжение предложения, при котором данная запятая понадобилась бы.

Об отсутствии практически всегда необходимости в разделении запятой сочинительного и подчинительного союзов **в начале предложения** говорят и современные правила.

См. [Валгина Н.С., Светлышева В.Н. *"Орфография и пунктуация"*, М., 2008]:

> **В начале предложения** сочинительный и подчинительный союзы, как
>   правило, не разделяются запятой (сочинительный союз здесь имеет
>   присоединительное значение)…

О том же говорится и в [**ПАС**](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=134#pp134):

> **§ 123…**
>
> <…>
>
> 3. **В начале предложения** не разделяются запятой сочинительный и подчинительный союзы, а также подчинительный союз и союзное слово...